# Get part out of string based on a specific value with batch

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have the following code:

```
SET location_path=\\dc01\intern\Product\NightlyBuild\Reg\Reg_20171207.1\out\site
OR
SET location_path=\\dc01\intern\Product\Release\ex\17.12\site
```

Now I want to get the following values out of the variables:

```
location_path_trimmed = Reg\Reg_20171207.1
OR
location_path_trimmed = 17.12
```

So for each path a different section should be taken out of the variable. So for example I need a method that search for the word: "**NightlyBuild**" or "**Release**" in order to retrieve the desired value. I tried to do this by using left string methods like:

```
%location_path:~0,4%
```

But that does not work. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Direction: recursive `FOR /F "delims=\ tokens=1,*" ...`

Comment: Do not use default system environment variable names, such as `%Path%`!

Comment: @Compo yes good point! I will modify it

Comment: What did you try by the code `%location_path:~0,4%`? it does not suit what you describe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `echo %str% | find /i "Release"` to test for Release, etc.  You could then use a `for /F` loop to tokenize the parts of the path value with `/` as a delimiter.  Or if the components you need to strip might be in unpredictable token positions, you could instead use variable substring substitution to strip off the parts you need.

Here's an example demonstrating the substring substitution method:

```js
@echo off & setlocal

SET "location_path=\\dc01\intern\Product\NightlyBuild\Reg\Reg_20171207.1\out\site"
call :trim "%location_path%" trimmed || exit /b 1
set trimmed

SET "location_path=\\dc01\intern\Product\Release\ex\17.12\site"
call :trim "%location_path%" trimmed || exit /b 1
set trimmed

goto :EOF

:trim <path> <return_var>
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
set "orig=%~1"
echo(%~1 | find /i "NightlyBuild\" >NUL && (
    set "trimmed=%orig:*NightlyBuild\=%"
) || (
    echo(%~1 | find /i "Release\" >NUL && (
        set "trimmed=%orig:*ex\=%"
    ) || (
        endlocal
        >&2 echo Error: %~1 contains unexpected build info
        exit /b 1
    )
)

set trimmed=%trimmed:\out=&rem;%
set trimmed=%trimmed:\site=&rem;%
endlocal & set "%~2=%trimmed%" & goto :EOF
```

You'll notice that to strip the parts *before* your desired value, you can use a wildcard -- e.g. `set "trimmed=%orig:*NightlyBuild\=%"`.  Stripping the parts *after* your desired value requires a little more creativity: `set trimmed=%trimmed:\out=&rem;%`.  [See this page](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php) for more information on batch variable string manipulation.  You can also read about [creating functions in batch files](https://www.dostips.com/DtTutoFunctions.php) if desired.

Answer (score 1):

You might even get away with doing it like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "location_path=\\dc01\intern\Product\NightlyBuild\Reg\Reg_20171207.1\out\site"
Rem Set "location_path=\\dc01\intern\Product\Release\ex\17.12\site"

If /I "%location_path:\NightlyBuild\=%"=="%location_path%" (
    If /I Not "%location_path:\Release\=%"=="%location_path%" (
        Set "location_path_trimmed=%location_path:*\Release\=%")) Else (
    Set "location_path_trimmed=%location_path:*\NightlyBuild\=%")
Set "location_path_trimmed=%location_path_trimmed:*\=%"
Set "location_path_trimmed=%location_path_trimmed:\="&:"%"

Set location_path_trimmed 2>Nul
Pause
```

*For testing purposes, just switch the `Rem`ark between lines `2` and `3` as necessary.*